# Get a collection based on the property of an other collection with Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In a project I'm working on I have a database (that I cannot modify) with two tables (Item and ItemSupplier). There is no foreignkey in the db. In my EF6 I have created two objects (database first):

```
public class Item {
    public string ItemCode { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double SalesPrice { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSupplier {
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string AccountCode { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is a list of `Item` that belongs to a specific supplier. So my idea was to first get a list of `ItemSupplier` and then get the `Item` list using `Any()`:

```
public List<Item> GetItemsByAccountCode(string code)
{
    List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
    using(DbEntities context = new DbEntities())
    {
        // Get the list of items of a specific supplier
        List<ItemSupplier> itemSupList = context.ItemSupplier.Where(p => 
                                          p.AccountCode == code).ToList();

        // Get al the items based on the itemSupList
        // Below is not working
        itemList = context.Item.Where(p => itemSupList.Any(x => x.ItemCode));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my idea was to **first get a list of ItemSupplier** and then get the Item list using Any()

Why would you want to do that if you can get the desired result with a single LINQ to Entities query like this:

```
itemList = context.Items.Where(item => db.ItemSupplier.Any(supplier =>
    supplier.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && supplier.AccountCode == code))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public List<Item> GetItemsByAccountCode(string code)
{
    List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
    using(DbEntities context = new DbEntities())
    {
        // Get the list of items codes of a specific supplier
        var itemCodes = context.ItemSupplier
                               .Where(p => p.AccountCode == code)
                               .Select(p => p.ItemCode)
                               .ToList();

        // Get al the items based on the itemSupList
        // Below is not working
        itemList = context.Item.Where(p => itemCodes.Contains(p.ItemCode));
    }
}
```